# Insert dynamic tables into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I take several hours thinking about how to do this, I need to insert various kinds of tables in a mysql table to store dynamic information about the clients of a company, similar to excel for example:

Table 1:

```
 Id|Name|Address|Phone Number
```

Table 2:

```
 Id|Name|package|delivered
```

Table 3:

```
 Id|Name|address|attendant|package|delivered
```

How I can do this without creating a mysql table for each? since different tables are handled. I consider use JSON to store each title and create it dinamically

This can be done easily in Excelbut it needs that the information is available online as needed

Comment: is mysql your only option?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table like this, and then populate the table_name field with each individual table "Name", and then just populate whatever fields you need.  You could add as many fields as you need.

```
CREATE TABLE `dynamic_table` (
  `table_name` VarChar(500),
  `Field_1` VarChar(500),
  `Field_2` VarChar(500),
  `Field_3` VarChar(500),
  `Field_4` VarChar(500),
  `Field_5` VarChar(500),
  `Field_6` VarChar(500),
  `Field_7` VarChar(500),
  `Field_8` VarChar(500),
  `Field_9` VarChar(500),
  `Field_10` VarChar(500)
);
```